# Psalms 146 vs. order of morning Brachos

Tags: tefilla, prayer-book, tehilim-psalms

[Tehilim 146 verse 7-8](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16367) says as follows:

> עֹשֶׂה מִשְׁפָּט לַעֲשׁוּקִים נֹתֵן לֶחֶם לָרְעֵבִים ה׳ מַתִּיר אֲסוּרִים׃
>   ה׳ פֹּקֵחַ עִוְרִים ה׳ זֹקֵף כְּפוּפִים ה׳ אֹהֵב צַדִּיקִים׃

However in the morning Brachos, according to Siddurim I am familiar with such as Artscroll, Metsudah, Koren, פֹּקֵחַ עִוְרִים is prior to מַתִּיר אֲסוּרִים. Why was the order changed for the morning Brachos?

[Siddur Hagra](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21127&st=&pgnum=17)

[Siddur Bais Yaakov](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42759&st=&pgnum=58)

Comment: It's an interesting Q. But, why should the order of the Brachot follow the same order as what is in Tehillim? How is one connected to the other?

Comment: @DanF: I would think that Tefila would be based on scripture, and follow its order. It is definite that it was not just haphazardly determined as to what order the prayers are said.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Talmud ([Berachot 60b](http://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.60b?lang=he&layout=block&sidebarLang=all)), the morning blessings are each said associated with specific acts of getting up in the morning:

> "כי פתח עיניה לימא: "ברוך פוקח עורים"; כי תריץ ויתיב לימא: "ברוך מתיר אסורים
>
> When he opens his eyes let him say: "Blessed... Who openest the eyes of the blind." When he straightens himself and sits up let him say : "Blessed...Who loosest them that are bound."

Generally speaking, people open their eyes first before sitting up. (If one were to sit up first, presumably the order of the blessings would be reversed as well.)

When the custom subsequently evolved to be said all at once later in the synagogue, apparently, the order was not changed.